# Request and response objects

Tags: python, django

In Django Documentation, [Request and response objects | Django documentation | Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest)

> When a page is requested, Django creates an HttpRequest object that contains metadata about the request.

Amongst the sentence,`creates an HttpRequest object` is to create an instance.

Is it more fancy to mention `instance` as `object` to perform as a professional programmer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object is the object itself, instance is referring to the Class, so:
This foo object is an instance of the Foo class.

Comment: Could an object exist and be itself without referring to any Class?

Comment: No. This is only nomenclature, the same for methods and functions.

Comment: so function vs object while methods vs instance

Comment: No, i think there are no official nomenclature for this.